# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left| \frac {\ln(n)^d} {n^z} - \frac {\ln(n)^d} {n^{z_0}} \right|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} f_n : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of function where $A$ is a closed disk of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\forall z \in A: \Re(z)>\frac{1}{2}$ and
$$
f_n(z)=
\left|
\frac
{\ln(n)^d}
{n^z}
-
\frac
{\ln(n)^d}
{n^{z_0}}
\right|^2
$$
and $z_0 \in A$ and $d\geq0$ is an integer

I would like to know if the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
f_n(z)
$$
converges uniformly.

Comment: Note that $\lvert a-b\rvert^2 \leqslant \lvert a\rvert^2 + 2\lvert a\rvert\,\lvert b\rvert + \lvert b\rvert^2 \leqslant 2(\lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer i need the proof of uniform convergence, help me please

Comment: Weierstraß $M$ test?

Comment: ok @DanielFischer  thanks for your suggestions